# Column Count en HTML con la libreria MPDF de PHP

Tags: php, html5, css3, mpdf

Estoy intentando mostrar un pdf con columnas, pero no me acepta `column-count` de css
Mi código:

```
<style type="text/css">
#container
{
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}

.cols
{
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}

.box
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.box.one
{
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #d77575;
}

.box.two
{
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #dcbc4c;
}

.box.three
{
    background-color: #a3ca3b;
    height: 400px;
}

.box.four
{
    background-color: #3daee3;
    height: 500px;
}

.box.five
{
    background-color: #bb8ed8;
    height: 600px;
}

.box.six 
{
    background-color: #baafb1;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```
<div id="container" class="cols">
<div class="box one"></div>
<div class="box two"></div>
<div class="box one"></div>
<div class="box three"></div>
<div class="box two"></div>
<div class="box five"></div>
<div class="box one"></div>
<div class="box two"></div>
<div class="box six"></div>
<div class="box three"></div>
<div class="box two"></div>
```

Esto en el navegador sale perfecto, pero en el pdf, no sale nada. Alguna idea del problema o algun otro código de uso??

Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según la documentación de la librería, esta propiedad de css **NO** está soportada:

https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html

Puedes ver una referencia detallada del CSS soportado en términos de código en el repositorio de GitHub:

https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/src/CssManager.php

Comment: Gracias por la información. Sabeis alguna manera en la que pueda hacer algo como lo que intento pero sin el column count??